# How do I design the footnote number at the bottom of the page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

When I insert a footnote, a superscripted number appears. I don't want to change this, but I want to design the number that appears at the bottom of the page without changing the actual text content of the footnote. How do I apply a character style to all of these numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's an automatic way, I use the manual ;-)

- Find/replace searching for `~F` and replace it for the footnote
  character style

[image: find/replace]

The problem is that every footnote number changes to this character style, the superscript and the foot number.

- Open the **Document Footnotes Option** and change the Footnote
  Reference Number in Text → Character Style → **Ignore** and then to **None**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time posting your solution! It seems impossible that there wouldn't be a designated InDesign feature but I'll roll with this manual solution :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can create "char style" that makes your numbers look correct, then apply it with a GREP style.

Example.

GREP style - (under your footer paragraph style)

Apply Style: "my new footnote number character style"
To Text: ~F

But ADOBE REALLY should make this easier since it is standard for a lot of academic publications.